# SWIG: Unexpected results with numpy wrappers?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, swig

Not sure if this is a bug or a misunderstanding on my part. Any help much appreciated. A concise project demonstrating the issue is [here](https://github.com/g40/swig8bit.git)

I am wrapping some C++ functions that take a pointer to a buffer (8 bit signed or unsigned) and an int with the buffer length, typically following this pattern: some_function(char* buffer,int length)

Adopting the example [here](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/SWIG_NumPy_examples.html) produces a sane looking wrapper based on the following:

example.i:

```
%module example

%{
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
    #include "example.h"
%}

// https://raw.githubusercontent.com/numpy/numpy/master/tools/swig/numpy.i
%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
    import_array();
%}

//
%apply (char* INPLACE_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(char* seq, int n)}
%apply (unsigned char* INPLACE_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(unsigned char* seq, int n)}
%apply (int* INPLACE_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(int* seq, int n)}

// Include the header file with above prototypes
%include "example.h"
```

example.h:

```
// stubbed
double average_i(int* buffer,int bytes)
{
    return 0.0;
}
```

However running this test:

```
np_i = np.array([0, 2, 4, 6], dtype=np.int)
try:
    avg = example.average_i(np_i)
except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
try:
    avg = example.average_i(np_i.data,np_i.size)
except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
```

produces errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    avg = example.average_i(np_i)
TypeError: average_i expected 2 arguments, got 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    avg = example.average_i(np_i.data,np_i.size)
TypeError: in method 'average_i', argument 1 of type 'int *'
```

The first one makes sense but runs contrary to the example in the cookbook. The second though does not, the signature for average_i *is* `double average_i(int* buffer,int bytes)`

Where am I going wrong? TAIA.

[*Update1*]

%apply definitions changed as per Flexo's advice

```
// integer
%apply (int* INPLACE_ARRAY1,int DIM1) {(int* buffer,int bytes)}
// signed 8
%apply (char* INPLACE_ARRAY1,int DIM1) {(char* buffer,int bytes)}
// unsigned 8
%apply (unsigned char* INPLACE_ARRAY1,int DIM1) {(unsigned char* buffer,int bytes)}
```

functions `average_i` and `average_u8` now works as expected.

However `double average_s8(char* buffer,int bytes)` still fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 25, in <module>
    avg = example.average_s8(np_i8)
TypeError: average_s8 expected 2 arguments, got 1
```

Comment: I really don't mind being downvoted but _please_ be constructive? Why is this inadequately researched? State your reason!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `%apply` directive is wrong and doesn't match the function you're wrapping:

```
%apply (int* INPLACE_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(int* seq, int n)}
```

This won't match your function `average_i` because the argument names you give are different. Change your [`%apply` to match](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_nn13) the declaration that SWIG sees i.e.:

```
%apply (int* INPLACE_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(int* buffer,int bytes)}
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. Oddly this fixes ~66% of the problem, but not for the plain `char*` variety. I am using SWIG 4.0.0

Comment: char* tends to be a bit special because you hit the strings typemaps too.

Comment: time for SWIG then to bite the bullet and start using Clang ... thanks for all your help.